# nodejs function to string containing function's code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really really new to nodejs.
Is there any way to convert function content to string?
Something like, if I have:

```
function() {
    ....
}
```

I'd like to have "function() { .... }".

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Did you try `(function() {...}).toString()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions already have a `toString()` method... so just `(function() {}).toString()` should work.

For example, in the node REPL:

```
> (function() { console.log("hello"); }).toString()
'function () { console.log("hello"); }'
```

Here's a link to some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString).

Comment: @kamituel I believe `Function.prototype.toString()` is standard.  The `indentation` parameter referenced in the MDN docs is non-standard, but this solution doesn't rely on that.